# How to Set width of Layout according to the picture size pragmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to set the height and width of Relative layout according to the background picture height and width

Comment: please show your code..

Comment: Brother i simply set the default value of layout in xml . when i take picture from camera then i want to set the layout height and width according to the  image height and width

Answer (score 0):

Add [`android:adjustViewBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds)`="true"` to your `ImageView` and it will automatically resize to fit your image. Generally, you set one dimension to a fixed quantity or `match_parent` and the other dimension to `wrap_content`. This will ensure that one dimension will be changed as the aspect ratio and size of the image changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not big deal.

First,Collect image width and height.
After that using Relative.LayoutParam set image width and height to Layout Param and set param to relative layout.

You can add other rules with LayoutParam  if need.